# Ajax ошибка undefined

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Всем привет!
Я использую MySQL + PHP + Ajax
Ошибка похоже возникает после обработки ajax'ом:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#country_id').change(function () {
        var country_id = $(this).val();
        if (country_id == '0') {
            $('#region_id').html('<option>- Введите регион -</option>');
            $('#region_id').attr('disabled', true);
            return(false);
        }
        $('#region_id').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#region_id').html('<option>Загрузка...</option>');

        var url = 'get_regions.php';

        $.get(
            url,
            "country_id=" + country_id,
            function (result) 
            {
                var options = ''; 

                $(result.regions).each(function() 
                {
                    options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('region_id') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>';
                });

                $('#region_id').html('<option value="0">- Введите регион -</option>'+options);
                $('#region_id').attr('disabled', false);    
            },
            "json"
        );
    });
});
```

и приложу get_regions.php где идёт обработка региона:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "login", "pass", "base");
mysqli_query($connect, 'SET CHARACTER SET "utf8"');
mysqli_query($connect, 'SET NAMES "utf8"');

$country_id = @strval($_GET['country_id']);
//$country_id = 3159;

$regs = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `group` FROM `$country_id` ORDER BY `group`");

if ($regs) 
{
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($regs);      
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $num) 
    {
       $regions[$i] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($regs);   
       $i++;
    }     
    $result = array('regions'=>$regions);  
}
else 
{
    $result = array('type'=>'error');
}
print json_encode($result); 
?>
```

MySQL запрос работает хорошо (или нет), но отображается нужное количество регионов. Из-за чего undefined?

Comment: так и написано: "ошибка undefined"?

Comment: нет, просто в select вывело 44 раза undefined

Comment: добавьте в функцию-колбэк первой строчкой: `console.log(result);` и посмотрите, что выведет в консоль

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в success добавить
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
и обращайся  obj.regions

и print json_encode($result);  замени на echo json_encode($result);

Comment: неа, не помогло. Может быть я не так что-то сделал

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема в следующем коде

```
$(result.regions).each(function() {
  options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('region_id') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>';
});
```

Ты уверен что следует так обращаться к result? result.regions это не объект dom. попробуй просто пройтись циклом for по result.regions, а не методами jquery.
например так

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.regions.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + result.regions[i].region_id + '">' + result.regions[i].name + '</option>';
}
```

Comment: неа, не помогло